# Bootstrap Navbar toggler and submenus not showing in Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, plugins, navbar

Ive migrated my website with All-in-one migration plugin and everything seems to be ok but my nabvar is not showing submenus and on mobile is not woking toggle button.

1. I've already checked if the pages are there
2. The libraries are correctly included
3. In the footer before  tag I have the call of:
4. There is not javascript errors
5. Original wordpress version: 5.0.2 -> migrated wordpress version: 5.2.2

footer.php imports

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
```

Header.php imports

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

NAVBAR CODE IN header.php

```
<div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button> 
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><div class="hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-xl">
                        <span><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.gif" alt="" width="27px" /></span>
                        Snowbunnys
                    </div></a>
            </di>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu(array(
                'theme_location' => 'primary',
                'container' => 'div',
                'container_id' => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end',
                'menu_id' => false,
                'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
                'depth' => 3,
                'fallback_cb' => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()
            ));
            ?>
```

Comment: If you view your element inspector or source code in your browser, do you see the HTML of the navbar?

Comment: Just a reminder ... there is a dedicated site for [Wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) you may get faster answer there than here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, I just realized that the problem is: footer.php is not rendering in the DOM. that's why bootstrap not working correctly. Any ideas to fix it?